# Integration by tables query

Tags: integration

[image]

I seem to be struggling with this particular question. It is my understanding that in this situation, where du does not equal dx, that you must manipulate the original problem to accommodate for this? However I admit, I arrived at my answer through use of an online calculator and would like to have a clear understanding of this concept.

Answer (score 2):

With $u=5t$, the differential is $\mathrm du=5\,\mathrm dt$, or $\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm du}5$. The "manipulation" you mention is really just a matter of keeping track of this factor of $\frac15$. Then you have

$$\int\sqrt{25t^2-4}\,\mathrm dt=\int\sqrt{(5t)^2-2^2}\,\mathrm dt=\color{red}{\frac15}\int\sqrt{u^2-2^2}\,\mathrm du$$

which according to the table has an antiderivative of

$$\color{red}{\frac15}\left(\frac{5t}2\sqrt{(5t)^2-2^2}-\frac{2^2}2\ln\left|5t+\sqrt{(5t)^2-2^2}\right|+M\right)$$

$$\frac t2\sqrt{25t^2-4}-\frac25\ln\left|5t+\sqrt{25t^2-4}\right|+M$$

$$\frac1{10}\left(5t\sqrt{25t^2-4}-4\ln\left|5t+\sqrt{25t^2-4}\right|\right)+M$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\text{Let }\begin{bmatrix}u \\ \mathrm du \\ a\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5t \\ \mathrm dt \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$